# CentOS7 SSH can't connect localhost?

Tags: centos, ssh, hadoop

I'm configuring **Hadoop** environment.

1. I have use `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""` to generate `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`.
2. And use `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to set password-free login.
3. Now, I enter `ssh localhost` command and get this error: `The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.`

How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The authenticity of the host can't be established* just means that the host key is not present in *~/.ssh/known_hosts* and it needs to register it before allowing SSH to connect to it. Just type yes and it should work.

Also, don't forget to change the permissions of *~/.ssh/authorized_keys* to **0600** or the key won't be authorized due to wrong file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH client told you that this was the first time that you connected to that host, and asked you to confirm that you wanted to connect. You said no; since you refused to confirm the identity of the host the SSH client ended the connection.

Try again and say yes when the SSH client asks you to confirm the identity of the host.